# Update multiple rows using one query

Tags: sql, mysql, union

Can I update multiple rows using one query?

How to union following queries:

```
UPDATE tablename SET col1='34355' WHERE id='2'

UPDATE tablename SET col1='152242' WHERE id='44'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a virtual map table for this update.

```
update tablename
inner join (
    select '34355'  col1, '2'  id union all
    select '152242' col1, '44' id
) map on map.id = tablename.id
set tablename.col1 = map.col1
```

Using this pattern allows for easy expansion (just add rows to the map).  It also allows MySQL to more predictably choose an index on tablename.id for the normal JOIN operation.

Answer (score 3):

Can you? Sure. Should you? No way.

Think about the person looking at your code in five years. What's more readable, this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET col1='34355' WHERE id='2';
UPDATE tablename SET col1='152242' WHERE id='44';
```

or this (The Scrum Meister's answer):

```
UPDATE tablename SET col1 = IF(id='2', '34355','152242') WHERE id='2' OR id='44';
```

The second one is shorter, but it's a challenge to figure out exactly what it's doing. If you're worried about race conditions, make it a single transaction (in most modern DBMS):

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE tablename SET col1='34355' WHERE id='2';
UPDATE tablename SET col1='152242' WHERE id='44';
COMMIT;
```

That way you can be guaranteed no other query will run when row 2 is updated but row 44 is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `OR` clause combined with the `IF()` function (or `CASE WHEN...` for other RDBMS)

```
UPDATE tablename SET col1 = IF(id='2', '34355','152242')
WHERE id='2' OR id='44'
```

Comment: For a long set of updates, it'd be easier to just do individual update queries, rather than build this hideous monstrosity. The only upside to this version is that it'd sort-of-kinda-maybe simulate a transaction on non-transaction-aware databases.

Comment: @marc-b The OP asked regarding 2 rows. Another downside if the list is large, the parser may choose a table scan instead of a index merge.

Comment: Highly recommend individual queries. Answer is correct, though I suggest not using it.

Comment: Individual queries are a lot less efficient for a large number of updates on a large number of rows.  Using `IF` or `CASE` results in the table being scanned once instead of multiple times.

Comment: @jnk It is very possible that `id` is indexed. so a single query will not do a table scan. I do believe that cyberwiki's answer is the best.

Comment: @Scrum - apologies for my imprecise terminology...if you have multiple `UPDATE` statements, the table will be read/indexes seeked/scanned for each statement.  If you use an update with a `CASE` you are only processing each row once.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the only way you can update multiple rows in a single query is if your where clause matches multiple rows... and then every row will have the same values set.

Past that you can do funky stuff with expressions in your set clauses, but generally it's cleaner to do multiple queries, unless there's a very specific reason you can't.